# Query ejecutado en Python no retorna informacion de mi base de datos Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, sql

El problema es que estoy haciendo unas consultas a la base de datos oracle 9 desde mi script en python 2.7 con la ayuda de cx_oracle pero a la hora de imprimir los valores del cursor no retorna información la cual **SI EXISTE** en la base de datos.

He probado colocar los valores de cada campo del where con **comillas simples, sin comillas simples, con =to_char(##)** y nada que retorna la informacion.

Cabe destacar que todas las columnas de la tabla son Varchar(2) y que al hacer el query en el **gestor si me retorna informacion**.

A continuacion el código

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import cx_Oracle

ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
port = xxxx
SID = 'xxxxx'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
conector = cx_Oracle.connect('USER', 'PASS', dsn_tns)

cursor = conector.cursor()  #cursor


#AQUI EL QUERY
querystring ="""SELECT * FROM NOMBRE_TABLA 
where cia='1' 
and scia='2' 
and ccosto='1500' 
and line='00'
and fn='00'
and cta='12345678' """


cursor.execute(querystring)

cursor.fetchmany()

for c in cursor:
    print c
```

y no tengo informacion en el Shell de Python.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente hayas agotado los registros devueltos al hacer el `cursor.fetchmany()`, por lo que no ves nada más luego.

Podrías haberlo hecho así:

```
for row in cursor.fetchmany():
    print row
```

Si el resultado tuviera muchas líneas, tendrías que paginar la salida:

```
while True:
    for row in cursor.fetchmany():
        print row
    else:
        break
```

Pero, en general, los conectores python de base de datos están bastante optimizados y saben controlar los cursores de la base de datos. Deja que hagan su labor y no te preocupes de nada más que iterar con el cursor:

```
#cursor.fetchmany()

for row in cursor:
    print row
```